# Java8のNashornでrequireしたい

Tags: javascript, java, java8, reactjs

現在React.jsを使用してアプリケーションを作成しています。
ブラウザ側ではwebpackを使用してコンポーネントをrequireして使用しています。

React.jsのサーバサイドレンダリングを使用してレスポンスを返したいと考えているのですが、Nashornにはrequireが存在しないようなので、https://github.com/nodyn/jvm-npm を利用してrequireしようとしています。

しかし以下のようにreactをrequireすると

```
engine.eval("load('./dist/jsx/jvm-npm.js');");
engine.eval("var React = require('./node_modules/react/react');");
```

エラーが発生してしまいます。Nashornでrequireを使う方法はないのでしょうか。

> javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "process" is not defined
>   in ./dist/jsx/jvm-npm.js at line number 106 at column number 11   at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:564)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:548)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:528)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
>     at net.jirox.radarscope.RadarScope.render(RadarScope.java:35)   at
>   net.jirox.radarscope.RadarScopeTest.testRender(RadarScopeTest.java:32)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: ./dist/jsx/jvm-npm.js:106:11 ReferenceError: "process" is
>   not defined   at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$jvm_npm._L21$Require(./dist/jsx/jvm-npm.js:106)
>     at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval_.runScript(:1)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:498)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:206)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:378)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:546)
>     ... 29 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReferenceError: "process" is not defined`との事ですので、JavaScript のどこかでグローバル変数`process`を参照しようとして、未定義エラーになっていると推測されます。

読み込んでいるファイル`react/react.js`は、Browserify等のコマンドラインツールから読み込むことを想定しているようで、内部で`process.env.NODE_ENV`を参照しています。

読み込むファイルを`react/dist/react.js`か、`react/dist/react.min.js`に変更するとエラーは出なくなると思われます。

Comment: react/dist/react/react.jsであれば確かに問題はなかったのですが、react-routerでも同様にprocessが定義されていました。

そこで、`process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';`と使用する変数を用意して対応できました。